# MVC [HandleError] HandleErrorAttribute called twice when using global logging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

In an MVC3 web application I was using

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

to apply global error handling where the user was shown the 'Error' view if an unhandled exception occured.

For one particular View, I also wanted a different error view to be displayed if an unhandled exception occurred by decorating the method with  `[HandleError(View = "SpecialError")]`. This worked fine.

I then wanted to add global *logging* of unhandled exceptions. I created a custom HandleError attribute with logging code:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            // Write to log code
            base.OnException(context);
        }
    }
```

And updated RegisterGlobalFilters and method decoration to use this attribute name instead. This works generally but when an exception occurs within the method that is decorated with `MyHandleError(View = "SpecialError")]` the OnException method is called *twice*. I originally presumed that decorating the method with this attribute superseded the global handler, but it seems that it is simply added to (which makes more sense, but it isn't what I want). By calling OnException twice, the same exception is logged twice which must not happen. I don't think OnException is being called twice *because* it is a custom attribute - I believe this happens with the standard HandleError attribute also, it is simply now visible as I am creating a record of it.

Ultimately, I want to log all unhandled exceptions (once), while retaining the features offered by [HandleError], particularly setting different views for particular method exceptions. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I found a clean solution to this myself. Extending HandleError seemed like a good idea but now I think it was a step in the wrong direction. I didn't want to handle any errors differently, just write exceptions to log once before HandleError picked them up. Because of this, the default HandleError can be left in place as-is. Although OnException can be called multiple times, it appears to be entirely benign in the standard implementation of HandleErrorAttribute.

Instead I created an exception logging filter:

```
public class LoggedExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            // logging code
        }
    }
```

It doesn't need too inherit from `FilterAttribute` as it is just registered once within RegisterGlobalFilters alongside HandleErrorAttribute.

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LoggedExceptionFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

This allows exceptions to be logged neatly without changing the standard `[HandleError]` features

Comment: Hi, great solution, but how can you get more information from the source of the exception like the class/method name ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
         var exceptionHandled = context.ExceptionHandled;

         base.OnException(context);                          

         if(!exceptionHandled && context.ExceptionHandled)
           // log the error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom `IFilterProvider` which will check if the filter has already been applied to that action:

```
public class MyFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (!actionDescriptor.GetFilterAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(MyHandleErrorAttribute)))
        {
            yield return new Filter(new MyHandleErrorAttribute(), FilterScope.Global, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, instead of registering your filter with the `GlobalFilterCollection`, you would register your filter provider in  `Application_Start()`

```
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new MyFilterProvider());
```

**Alternatively** (similar to what @Mark proposed) you could explicitly set the `ExceptionHandled` property of `ExceptionContext`

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if(context.ExceptionHandled) return;

        // Write to log code
        base.OnException(context);
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the solution to keeping the OnException method from firing twice. If you are using In the FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters() method, comment-out the registering of the HandleErrorAttribute:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

In fact, I also used the built-in HandleErrorAttribute without registering it, and it worked fine. I only need to have custom errors turned on:

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should re-read the question.  He wants to use both at the same time.